# vstest with TFS build: System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: 'Object '/XXX.rem' has been disconnected or does not exist at the server

Tags: c#, tfsbuild, mstest, vstest, vstest.console.exe

I have a `x64 .NET 4.5.2 C#` solution with unit tests.

Unit tests are successfully running on my dev machine, but when running on TFS build with following command:

```
[command]"D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" m:\Workspace\MyApp\Tests\MyApp.Tests\bin\x64\Release\MyApp.Tests.dll /logger:trx "/TestAdapterPath:\"m:\Workspace\"" /Platform:x64
```

I'm getting the following log:

> Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 14.0.25420.1
>   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved. Starting
>   test execution, please wait...

5 minutes of hang and then

> Error: An exception occurred while invoking executor
>   'executor://mstestadapter/v2': Object
>   '/5243803c_c5e9_4f2c_bd7d_05acf3030dfa/veajeovlsl8zvqsxjaq47f1d_25.rem'
>   has been disconnected or does not exist at the server.

This always reproduces on build server, and I managed to one time reproduce it with debbugger and got following stack trace:

```
System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingException: 'Object '/5594bcf8_9093_482c_aa7b_bb6b6f25dd27/gudsmiyjksi5no4zhgahfzqu_9.rem' has been disconnected or does not exist at the server.'

>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.Execution.TestExecutionManager.ExecuteTestsWithTestRunner(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestCase> tests, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.Adapter.IRunContext runContext, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.Adapter.ITestExecutionRecorder testExecutionRecorder, string source, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.Execution.UnitTestRunner testRunner)    Unknown
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.Execution.TestExecutionManager.ExecuteTestsInSource(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestCase> tests, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.Adapter.IRunContext runContext, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.Adapter.ITestExecutionRecorder testExecutionRecorder, string source, bool isDeploymentDone)   Unknown
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.Execution.TestExecutionManager.ExecuteTests(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestCase> tests, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.Adapter.IRunContext runContext, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.Adapter.IFrameworkHandle frameworkHandle, bool isDeploymentDone)  Unknown
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.Execution.TestExecutionManager.RunTests(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestCase> tests, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.Adapter.IRunContext runContext, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.Adapter.IFrameworkHandle frameworkHandle, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.TestRunCancellationToken runCancellationToken)   Unknown
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTest.TestAdapter.MSTestExecutor.RunTests(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestCase> tests, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.Adapter.IRunContext runContext, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.Adapter.IFrameworkHandle frameworkHandle) Unknown
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Core.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Core.TestExecutionManager.RunTestInternalWithExecutors(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Uri> executorUris, bool hasTests, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.Uri, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>> executorUriVsSourceList, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<System.Uri, System.Collections.Generic.List<Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestCase>> executorUriVsTestList, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Core.RunContext runContext, long totalTests, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Common.Utilities.MeasurementBlockWrapper mb)    Unknown
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Core.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Core.TestExecutionManager.RunTestsInternal(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object> testOrSources, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.Adapter.IRunSettings runSettings, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Core.TestExecutionContext executionContext) Unknown
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Core.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Core.TestExecutionManager.RunTests(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object> testsOrSources, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.Adapter.IRunSettings runSettings, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Core.TestExecutionContext executionContext)    Unknown
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Core.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.Core.TestExecutionManager.RunTests(object data)    Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart(object obj)  Unknown
```

I've tried to use both `Visual Studio 2015` and `2017`, got same results.

My solution is using packages `MSTest.TestAdapter` and `MSTest.TestFramework` both of version 1.1.11

According to this thread: [Long running unit test marked as passed fails TFS build - Object 'xxx.rem' has been disconnected or does not exist at the server.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47534593/long-running-unit-test-marked-as-passed-fails-tfs-build-object-xxx-rem-has-b) ,

I tried to upgrade `MSTest` packages versions, but could never make them run locally with higher versions.

Also I've successfully run unit tests with other projects using 1.1.11 packages before.

Comment: The solution is to use MSTest 1.1.13 or later, as the answer in the link you provided suggests. If you're having a problem getting your tests to run with that version of MSTest, I'd ask a question about how to fix *that* problem. Since you've provided no details on what that problem is, I can't make any suggestions.

Comment: Feel like it could be related to the agent running in TFS. Since it is working locally...

Comment: @DanielMann you were right, upgrading to 1.1.18 solved the issue on build machine, still having problems locally but guessing that would be easier to solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, it's the MSTest issue on old version.

So, the solution is upgrading the MSTest to 1.1.13 or later version on the build agent machine.